# Getting input from just one Axis at a time

Tags: unity, 2d, movement, input

I'm trying to make a `CharacterController2D` Script for a simple 2D TopDown game, but i was wondering, what would be the best way to disable 2-axis movement? just allowing one direction at a time (Maybe similar to the old Pokemon games)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Input.GetKeyDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) and [Input.GetKeyUp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html) and do something like:

Uses `GetKeyDown` to test if your "Move on X axis" key is pressed, if true, disable moving on the Y axis by setting a flag. Do the same for the Y axis.

Now you just need to use `GetKeyUp` to reset a flag on a particular axis. ie. if the "Move on Y axis" key is released, you have to reset the flag preventing you from moving on X axis.

```
if (canMoveOnX && Input.GetKeyDown(X_KEY))
{
    canMoveOnY = false;
    Move(X);
}
if (canMonveOnY && Input.GetKeyDown(Y_KEY))
{
    canMoveOnX = false;
    Move(Y);
}

if (Input.GetKeyUp(X_KEY))
{
    canMoveOnY = true;
}
if (Input.GetKeyUp(Y_KEY))
{
    canMoveOnX = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you decided to use GetAxis or GetKey... but you can compare both axis everytime the player can move (when the move animation is over) and use only the more important one. As GetAxis returns a value between -1.0f and 1.0f if you check the absolute value of both axis then you'd know which direction is asked by the player.

For example:

```
float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("horizontal");
float vertical = Input.GetAxis("vertical");

if ( horizontal != 0.0f || vertical != 0.0f ) // if player asked to move
{
    // if the pressure is more important on the horizontal axis
    if ( Mathf.Abs(horizontal) >= Mathf.Abs(vertical) ) // note that if both values are equals the default behaviour will be to chose horizontal axis.
    {
        // Move on horizontal axis
    }
    else
    {
        // Move on vertical axis
    }
}
```